# git - How to undo a "git repack -ad"?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repository that i have packed with `git repack -a -d`, this repacked all the objects into one big file. This saves space. However I want to undo this, and turn that one big pack file into all the little object files.

The reason I want to do this is to backup the git repository to a remote server. I did a backup (before repacking). Installing git on the remote server is nontrivial, so I was going to use `rsync` to copy the files. However rsync is not this clever and will basically want to copy things again. If I can 'unpack' this repository, it might make it quicker to copy.

Comment: Well, even if you can unpack it, I doubt you can get it into the exact same set of packs/objects as before.

Comment: This is true — git will occasionally (when the number of objects grows large) produce a pack automatically, so you will eventually be forced to move a new pack.

Comment: I'm happy if it's not exactly the same. It would be nice to be able to improve things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[git-unpack-objects](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-unpack-objects.html) will unpack the objects, but only inside a repo that *doesn't* contain the pack:

Make a new, empty repo:

```
mkdir new-repo; cd new-repo; git init
```

Write the objects in:

```
git unpack-objects < ../old-repo/.git/objects/pack/pack-XXX.pack
```

Pull the necessary branches/tags in:

```
git pull ../old-repo
```

Or, if you're adventurous, you could attempt to use the objects directory in `new-repo` as a replacement for the old one.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, git-unpack-objects will work just fine *if* you first rename or move the pack file.  It's designed to add an incoming pack to a repository, adding all objects that aren't already there.  Just moving the pack file to a file name where git can't find it will make all its objects unfindable.

Basically:

```
mv .git/objects/pack .git/objects/pack.old
for i in .git/objects/pack.old/pack-*.pack; do
    git-unpack-objects < $i && rm $i ${i%pack}idx
done
rmdir .git/objects/pack.old
```

However, be aware that a pack file is *much* smaller than the loose objects (because loose objects don't do delta-compression against each other), and while Linus originally intended to do exactly what you're doing (loose objects only and use rsync), he quickly found that it was unworkable.

The right way to do it is to repack once (with aggressive parameters to minimize the size) and then create a .keep file (if `$i` is `pack-*.pack`, you want to `touch ${i%pack}keep`).  This will make the created pack file "sacred" and it will never be removed or repacked.

Then you can use rsync on the "leftover" pack, until it gets big enough to warrant bundling into a second .keep shunk.

A third way to do it would be to use `git-bundle` to make a pack containing just the deltas since the last backup.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a

```
fast-export | fast-import
```

into a fresh repo. Chances are that no packing will be triggered. 
Otherwise you can tweak the config for pack (`man git config`, search for pack.*)